# Server Stopped While Executing The Invocable On Second Request

Tags: java, v8, j2v8

While executing the following line my server halted for the second request.

```
Invocable invocableEngine =  load();
Object o1 = invocableEngine.invokeFunction("add",5,6,jsonObj);


 private static Invocable invocable =null;
 public static Invocable load() throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException, FileNotFoundException {
        if(invocable!=null){
            return invocable;
        }
    File jsFile = new File("test.js");

        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("jav8"); //No I18N
        Reader reader = new FileReader(jsFile);

        engine.eval(reader);
        invocable = (Invocable) engine;
        return invocable;
    }
```

test.js

```
add = function(a, b) {
return a + b;
}
```

I dont want to evaluate the js for each request, so that i used the Invocable as static.

This is the error thrown in the console

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000121d6f4b4, pid=791, tid=33539
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b17) (build
>   1.8.0_25-b17)  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)  Problematic frame:  C 
>   [libjav8651059438244345661.dylib+0x184b4] 
>   _ZN2v811HandleScopeC1Ev+0x84
>
> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable
>   core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as: 
>   hs_err_pid791.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp  The crash happened
>   outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.  See problematic
>   frame for where to report the bug.